# how to repopulate a form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to repopulate a codeigniter form, when I click the submit button the form input disappears. I have tried to use the set value function but its not working, I am auto loading the form helper.

form view

```
 <?php $attributes= array('id'=>'registration_form','class'=>'registration_form');?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-8 columns">
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('reg_errors')):?>

<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('reg_errors');?>

<?php endif;?>
  </div>
</div>


<?php echo form_open('User/registration_check',$attributes);?>

<div class="registration_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 large-offset-8 columns">

<?php 

$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'id'=>'fname',
'name'=>'fname',
'placeholder'=>'First Name',
'value'=> set_value('fname')


);

echo form_input($data);
?>

    </div>
       <div class="large-2 columns">

<?php 

$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'lname',
'placeholder'=>'Last Name'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-8 columns">
<?php 

$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'email',
'placeholder'=>'Email'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
    </div>

</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-8 columns">

<?php 

$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'cemail',
'placeholder'=>'Confirm Email'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>

    </div>

</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-8 columns">

<?php 

$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'password',
'placeholder'=>'Password'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>

    </div>

</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-offset-8 columns">

<?php 


$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'cpassword',
'placeholder'=>'Confirm Password'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>

    </div>



 <div class="large-1 large-offset-8 columns">
<?php echo "<select name='day' id='day'><option value='default'>day</option>";
for($i=1; $i<32; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'".($i==$_POST["day"] ? " selected" : null).">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";?>
    </div>
<div class="medium-1 columns">
  <?php
echo "<select name='month' id='month'><option value='default'>month</option>";
for($i=1; $i<13; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'".($i==$_POST["month"] ? " selected" : null).">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns">

<?php
echo "<select name='year'id='year'><option value='default' >year</option>";
for($i=1900; $i<2016; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'".($i==$_POST["year"] ? " selected" : null).">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 large-offset-9 columns">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-2 large-offset-2 columns">
<?php

$data = array(

'class'=>' success button',
'name'=>'register',
'id'=>'register',
'value'=>'Register'


);?>
<?php echo form_submit($data);?>

 </div>
 </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

user controller

```
class User extends CI_Controller {



    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('templates/head');
        $this->load->view('templates/home_header');
        $this->load->view('webPages/home');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


          public function registration_check() {


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cemail','Confirm Email','trim|required|matches[email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','Firstname','trim|required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Lastname','trim|required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Confirm Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique','email already in use'); 


     if($this->form_validation->run()) {



        //generates a random key 
        $key = md5(uniqid());

        $this->load->library('email',array('mailtype'=>'html'));
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $this->email->from('c3392262@joshpercival.co.uk',"joshua percival");
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
        $this->email->subject("Account Confirmation");

        $message = "<p>Thank you for signing up</p>";
        $message .= "<p><a href ='".base_url()."index.php/Users/register_user/$key'>Click here</a> to confirm your account</p>";

        $this->email->message($message);

        if( $this->User_model->add_temp($key)) {

        if($this->email->send()){
       $data['title'] = 'Confirmation Email Sent';
       $email['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
       $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
       $this->load->view('authentication/email_sent_success',$email);
       } else {
           echo 'email was not sent';
       }
        } else {
            echo 'could not add to database';
        }


        //add to temp database 


    } else {
          $data = array(

            'reg_errors'=> validation_errors()
            );
               $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
         redirect('User/index');


    }


    }
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39943730/edit) your question and include the controller `User` and the `User::index()` code.

Comment: iv added my user controller

Comment: Does the form fail to reappear when you have purposely posted with invalid fields? Or does it fail to reappear when you provide what should be valid fields? Or, does it fail no matter what state the fields are in?

Comment: when the submit button is pressed the values that are in the form, disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this block of code

```
} 
else 
{
  $data = array('reg_errors'=> validation_errors());
  $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
  redirect('User/index');
}
```

You cannot use redirect with form_validation in this way and retain the instance of `form_validation` you have been using.

With the redirect the server discards your current instance of CI (and all loaded classes - including form_validation) and then will create a whole new instance of CI. The `set_value()` function uses information gathered by `form_validation->run()` but that is long gone. It has no information to use to repopulate the forms.

Take another very close look at the [Form Validation Tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial) and notice there is no `redirect` call involved.